# How to check if there is a weekend between two dates in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime, laravel-5

I want to check if there is any sat or sun between two dates in php.

```
$fromDate = '03/21/2016';
$toDate = '03/28/2016';
```

I've tried other solution asked here but they didn't worked well. I want it in laravel 5.2 so if there is any easy way to handle this please guide me. thanks!

**Update**
i also want to get if there is weekday(mon-fri) between two dates. i need it because user can select sat and Sunday only so in this condition I've to hide weekday option from him. So what I need is a method which tells me if start and end date has weekend or weekdays or both in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `date("N")` to get the current day of the week and add the difference of days between your dates... If this is bigger or equal to 6 than it's a weekend between or one date is in the weekend.

```
//Get current day of week. For example Friday = 5
$day_of_week = date("N", strtotime($fromDate));

$days = $day_of_week + (strtotime($toDate) - strtotime($fromDate)) / (60*60*24);
//strtotime(...) - convert a string date to unixtimestamp in seconds.
//The difference between strtotime($toDate) - strtotime($fromDate) is the number of seconds between this 2 dates. 
//We divide by (60*60*24) to know the number of days between these 2 dates (60 - seconds, 60 - minutes, 24 - hours)
//After that add the number of days between these 2 dates to a day of the week. So if the first date is Friday and days between these 2 dates are: 3 the sum will be 5+3 = 8 and it's bigger than 6 so we know it's a weekend between.



if($days >= 6){
  //we have a weekend. Because day of week of first date + how many days between this 2 dates are greater or equal to 6 (6=Saturday)
} else {
  //we don't have a weekend
}
```

Comment: it worked. thanks! can you please explain it's working so i can understand too what's happening here.

Comment: I've a question, your solution tell if there is any weekend between two dates. what if i want to get if there is weekday(mon-fri) between two dates? i need it because user can select sat and sunday only so in this condition i've to hide weekday option from him.

Comment: @UmairMalik I updated my answer with comments so you can understand better what it does. Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<?php
    $is_weekend = 0;
    $fromDate = strtotime('2016-03-21');
    $toDate = strtotime('2016-03-28');
    while (date("Y-m-d", $fromDate) != date("Y-m-d", $toDate)) {
        $day = date("w", $fromDate);
        if ($day == 0 || $day == 6) {
            $is_weekend = 1;
        }
        $fromDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $fromDate) . "+1 day");
    }
    echo $is_weekend;
```

hoe it helps :)